# How to connect ethereum wallet to ganache?

Tags: ganache

Can anyone list out the steps  on how to connect the ethereum wallet to ganache?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

The following command should run the wallet for port `8545` . If Ganache is running on `7545` change the command accordingly.

```
ethereumwallet --rpc http://localhost:8545
```